# How to use a federated React module if the host React application isn't using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have two React applications. One is the remote app, and other is the host app. The remote app uses Webpack 5 using which I have federated the module. The host app uses Rollup for all purposes. I want the host application to use the federated module. How can I achieve this?

The below is how we have exposed the remote app which is running on port 3000.

```
            name: "ResetPassword",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            remotes: {},
            exposes: {
                "./ResetPassword": "./src/pages/create-password",
            },
            shared: { 
                ...packageJsonDeps,
                react: { singleton: true, requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps.react },
                "react-dom": { singleton: true, requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps["react-dom"] }
            },
        })
```

Comment: Please add: 1. How is `packageJsonDeps`defined? 2. webpack file for host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This official Module Federation example](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/rollup-federation-demo) solves exactly this issue.

Basically -

1. In Rollup host - add Module federation in the plugins section of the config.
   a. define `remotes`.
   b. define `shared`
2. Add Rollup remote in MF app.

Check [this article](https://medium.com/@jacobebey/module-federation-in-rollup-js-b79783a7f397) for a simplistic walkthrough

btw it's good practice to define the shared libraries/packages in your package.json something like

```
shared: require('../package.json').dependencies
```